# Is there any method to call B class function and C class function via D?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class B
{
    public : 
    void fun()
    {
        cout<<"class B\n";
    }
};
class C 
{
    public :
    void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Class C\n";
    }
};
class D:public B,public C
{
    public :
    void funD()
    {
        cout<<"Class D\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: `D d; d.C::fun(); d.B::fun();`???

Comment: Or just `B::fun();` from inside `D`.